# How to access this.app and/or a injected plugin in a Vuex store test with Nuxt and Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, nuxt.js

In a Vuex store action, I'm using this.app.router and a Nuxt plugin that injects the property $alert.

When I'm trying to test the Vuex store with Jest the test keeps failing because both of the properties are undefined.

I'm unit testing the getters, mutations, and actions separately as a javascript function like described [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-a-vuex-store).

So not using Vue Test Utils or Vuex.

What I've already tried without any effect:

- setup a new `Vuex.Store` and `localVu`e from `vue-test-utils`.
- setting a global variable with properties app and `$alert` before the test.

```
// actions.js
export default {
  async signup({ dispatch, state }, payload) {
      try {
        await dispatch('createUserData', payload)
        await dispatch('setUser', payload)
        this.app.router.push(state.redirectAfterLogin)
      } catch (error) {
        this.$alert.error(`errors.${error.code}`)
      }
  }
}

// actions.spec.js
import actions from '@/store/auth/actions'

describe('Auth store', () => {
  let dispatch
  let state

  test('signup', async () => {
    dispatch = jest.fn()
    state = {
      user: null
    }
    await actions.signup(
      { dispatch, state },
      {
        email: 'test@test.nl',
        password: 'password',
        displayName: 'Test'
      }
    )
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('createUserData')
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('setUser')
  })
})
```

Someone has any idea where and how I can define this method as mock functions in my test file?

Comment: Same issue here - have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. use `localVue` with Vuex
2. mock `$alert
    Vuex.Store.prototype.$alert = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({})`

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy actions are pure functions when you are testing them separately
just before `await actions.signup` add :
`actions.$alert ={}; actions.$alert.error =jest.fn();`
or even better add it in beforeEach function